# print/watch a variable in a file of a large code base using GDB?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I want to add `watch` or `print` a specific global variable defined and declared in a particular file of a large code-base. So, it is possible that multiple variables of same name with different `Linkage`exists in the code-base. I know how to add watch or print a local and global variable in a single file project using `GDB`.

I am using `gdb` on my `Ubuntu` machine. I tried google but couldn't get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is documented on this page: https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Variables.html#Variables

In summary you need to use the following syntax to select a particular variable by file:

```
(gdb) print 'file.c'::variable
```

And this can also be used for watchpoints too:

```
(gdb) watch -l 'file.c'::variable
```

Comment: What to do if it says `No symbol "file.c" in current context.`? Also, there can be several files named `file.c` in different directories, how to choose specific one? (In my use case it's actually `file.go`, but my issue can be language-agnostic)

Comment: For golang correct syntax was `print 'my_app/my_lib.my_var'` in my case(it was difficult to guess and impossible to google)